# React Native App Crash (Thread 1: EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=1, address=0x54))

Tags: ios, xcode, react-native

Recently came onto this issue when trying to run my app on the simulator through xCode or the React Native CLI. The bundle loads from localhost then the app immediately crashes with "Thread 1: EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=1, address=0x54)" in "main.m" in Xcode. I am unable to get the app running even though it builds fine. (even tried running on release instead of debug)

[image: error in main.m]

This issue just started recently occurring and I cannot find anything in our Git logs that would cause any kind of issue - all pretty minor changes on the RN side and nothing native. Has anyone seen this issue/knows how to properly trace it? Seems like a super generic error and it is unclear on how to figure out what is actually going on.

Xcode version 11.5, React Native 0.62.0, and targetting iOS 10.

EDIT:
After running the app a few times I was able to get this error in the Xcode Output

[image: Xcode output]

Comment: Just for clarification I've taken all basic steps - removing libraries that were added since this started happening, cleared build folders, checked Xcode settings, reset simulator cache, etc. Tried all basic things I could think of before posting.

Comment: it is kind hard to fix without reproduction example, but you can take a look at https://riptutorial.com/ios/example/16684/debugging-exc-bad-access or https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/what-is-exc_bad_access-and-how-to-debug-it--cms-24544

Comment: Can you share more of your output from Xcode?

Comment: Yes, I figured its hard to identify without a repo example, if I was able to reproduce outside our project I'd be able to solve the problem. I am unable to identify any changes in the last couple days that make any difference on the native side - everything has mainly been JSX styling changes. I will also grab the full xCode output and edit it in.

Comment: @DougWatkins I have updated the question with the full output

Comment: I have tried every fix I could find in the github repos that have this same issue - https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/21030#issuecomment-423094675 and https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/22140 , seems like I'm the only one in 2020 so far to come across this.

Comment: `Socket SO_ERROR [61: Connection refused]` I have this error on working application, don't think it is the issue

Comment: Have any of your Packages been updated/changed recently?

Comment: @DougWatkins nothing I can pinpoint. This must be a deeper error withing the javascript code because if I comment out all the code in app.tsx I am able to return a View. Doesn't make sense that it's just showing itself now as nothing in the core code has changed before this started occurring, oh well.

Comment: We had something like this happen once because we deleted the podfile.lock and yarn.lock and reinstalled things. It updated a package that we weren't prepared for. This error most definitely is a Native error and not directly caused by your javascript, except in the case of your javascript initiating some native code to run.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After tons of debugging, confusion, and many hours of frustration it came down to removing and readding one dependency. There was no specific error message I could trace or change I could find in our git history that would've caused this. I literally ended up tediously removing code from the App until I found the library that was the problem.

Comment: So which library was it?

Comment: @philk sorry it's been so long I can't remember, I literally had to go one by one removing dependencies until it was fixed. Wish I had a better solution, stupid error.

Comment: In my case was a dependency that was with some version taken from a different registry I would assume, since I was not the one who installed it. 
Maybe if there is some dependency that for sure reads from memory and has a unusual version in package.json could be a cause. 
in my case was `react-native-audio-decorder`

Comment: For me it was `react-native-maps`. This is only happening on simulator and works fine on physical device.

Comment: In my case it's react-native-picker. Latest version as of today

Answer (score 4):

For me, running this `watchman watch-del-all && yarn cache clean` was what worked. I found it on an issue on github. Strange but it worked like magic